# Why does Visual Studio 2019 does not Clean or Rebuild Solution for any of my C# solutions/projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019 (**updated to version 16.8.6**) installed.
After I updated to 16.8.6, I can no longer clean/build any of my solutions.
The same occurs if I use a simple sample solution.

When I right click the solution in the **Solution Explorer** and select "**Clean Solution**"
I get the following error in the **Build Output Window**:

> ========  Clean: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped =======

When I right click and select "Rebuild Solution"
I get the following in the **Build Output Window**:

> Rebuild started... 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BowlingGame,
> Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Restoring NuGet packages... To
> prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual
> Studio Options dialog, click on the NuGet Package Manager node and
> uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
> Running restore with 12 concurrent jobs. Reading project file
> C:\DevSamples\TDD\BowlingGame - Daily Kata\BowlingGame.csproj.
> Restoring packages for C:\DevSamples\TDD\BowlingGame - Daily
> Kata\BowlingGame.csproj... Restoring packages for
> .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1... Resolving conflicts for
> .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1... Checking compatibility of packages on
> .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1. Checking compatibility for BowlingGame 1.0.0
> with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1. All packages and projects are
> compatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1. Committing restore...
> Writing cache file to disk. Path: C:\DevSamples\TDD\BowlingGame -
> Daily Kata\obj\project.nuget.cache Assets file has not changed.
> Skipping assets file writing. Path: C:\DevSamples\TDD\BowlingGame -
> Daily Kata\obj\project.assets.json Persisting dg to
> C:\DevSamples\TDD\BowlingGame - Daily
> Kata\obj\BowlingGame.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
>
> NuGet Config files used:
> C:\Users\jxbma\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
> C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\DevExpress .NET Core Desktop 19.2.config
> C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\DevExpress 18.2.config
> C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\DevExpress 19.1.config
> C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\DevExpress 19.2.config
> C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config
> C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Xamarin.Offline.config
>
> Feeds used:
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
> https://repo.didisoft.com/repository/openssl/ Restored C:\DevSamples\TDD\BowlingGame - Daily Kata\BowlingGame.csproj (in 2
> ms).
> C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 19.2.NET Core Desktop Libraries\System\Components\Packages
> C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 18.2\Components\System\Components\Packages
> C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 19.1\Components\System\Components\Packages
> C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 19.2\Components\System\Components\Packages
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages
> https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SteelCloudLLC/index.json NuGet package restore finished.
> ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I get no additional error information.
I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2019 and still get the same errors.
Is something cached/corrupted that I'm unaware of?
I'm getting this behaviour across all my solutions.

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: Try Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build And Run, and then change the MSBuild output verbosity. Might help you find the issue...

Comment: As @Kit stated, change "MSBuild project build output verbosity". Set to "Diagnostic". What version did you upgrade from? Have you tried with any projects that don't use NuGet packages? Since you're using NuGet, ensure that Tools => Options => NuGet Package Manager => General => Package Management => Default package management format has the correct setting. If your solution folder has a "packages" folder, then it should be set to "Packages.config". You can also look at the .csproj file for your project. If you see "<PackageReference ...>" then the setting should be "PackageReference".

Comment: Verbosity is already set to Diagnostic. No output for clean. Diagnostic output for Rebuild All.

Comment: These issues are occurring even when I create a new .Net core console  sample project.

Comment: @JohnB, based on my test, I can rebuild and clean solution correctly. I suggest that you can report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8).

Comment: OK finally figured it out. Building in .Net Core for some reason, error messages weren't displayed. Building a .Net console app produced same result, but pointed me to: C:\Users\jxbma\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuild* for build error messages. Which in turn pointed me to: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Project-issues-after-1682-update-chil/1263614?preview=true. Once I removed System.Memory from the GAC, I have been abled to clean/rebuild solutions.